# how to set cron correctly on a shared server

Tags: 6, cron

I set the following command for cron on a shared server.

```
/usr/bin/php5.3 home/public_html/cron.php
```

(All the Drupal files are under /public_html)

This commend seems to be working but I get the following error

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/public_html/sites/default/settings.php:1) in /home/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1163
Sorry,  has been banned.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like perhaps you settings.php file has some extra characters outside of the